# How to check three if statement in Javascript in map function?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have three statement in map function.
Check code first:

let Myarray.map( item => { 
    if( (item.id == null || item.name == null) || item.size === undefined) {
     return 'this is error'
    }

check I need. If the first of the two conditions is null or "" return error, and also if the third condition is undefined also return error. But if neither is okay it is ..more precisely if any of these conditions are not true return the error.

myArray is array like [{id: 1, name : "test" , size : 1}] ...and more more object in array...

Comment: "If any of these conditions are not true, return the error" <= that is the complete inverse of what you are currently doing, which is to return the error if *any are true*

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to throw an error if any of the properties are missing. In that case, you need to put the code in a try/catch. I also recommend adding the code in a function, so you can call it multiple times (like I did in the code below), and I also recommend that you refactor the if statement into a function of its own to make the code more readable.

I mostly added console.logs in order to see the results. The returns are mostly there if you want to handle the error in any way.

---

You had two major flaws in your code. You got an extra parenthesis after `item.name == null` and you can't really return something inside the map function. Any return inside the map function will change the item in the new array returned from `map`.

```js
function anyPropertyIsMissingIn(item) {
  return item.id == null || item.name == null || item.size == undefined;
}

function checkPropertiesIn(arr) {
  try {
    arr.map((item, index) => {
      if (anyPropertyIsMissingIn(item)) {
        throw `Error at index ${index}`;    
      }

      return item;
    });

    console.log("Fully validated array");
    
    return true;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
}

let myArray =  [{id: 1, name: "test", size: 1}]; // Fully validated array
let myArray2 = [{id: 1, name: "test"}];          // Error at index 0

checkPropertiesIn(myArray);
checkPropertiesIn(myArray2);
```